# Special character &ndash; on href

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, special-characters, href

I have on a js file constants contents strings to use on href in other pages. When I use – the dash on the url is bigger then normal dash and it doesn't work. When I manually substituted the dash on URL in browser with a normal dash, it works and the link is open. How can I do to solve this issue?

example:

```
"MYSTRING" : "first text, then </br><a class=\"my_class\" href=\"/speed/my&ndash;site\" target=\"_blank\">My Link</a>"
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```
function decodeEntity(str) {
var txt = document.createElement("div");
txt.innerHTML = str;
return txt.innerHTML;
}
$('a').attr('href',decodeEntity('/speed/my&ndash;site'));
```

Comment: Hi @Amit Gupta, I can't cause the <a> tag is inside a string, a constant. I can't use this method.

Comment: I updated my question with a better example. Thank you

Comment: Hi @Spicchio - So you mean "<a href='/speed/my&ndash;site'>My Link</a>" , some thing like this in js file?

Comment: It is a constant. I updated my question with a better example just now

Comment: @Spicchio- you can concat string as shown below:
`"MYSTRING" : "first text, then </br><a class=\"my_class\" href=\"" + decodeEntity("/speed/my&ndash;site/") + "\" target=\"_blank\">My Link</a>";`

Comment: @Spicchio - Updated my comment again , some error fix.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201667/discussion-between-amit-gupta-and-spicchio).

Comment: Everything exploded. It is not working, I have to use something else